# Eclipse: local member color

Tags: eclipse

I'm forced to ditch my trusty Eclipse Indigo and move on to something newer. I've managed to make it look the same using General -> Appearance -> Theme: Classic, but I can't find how to change the color for local variables to black, instead of brown/gray.

How do I make `localVariable` black, not brown/gray?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to *Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Syntax Coloring*, select *Java -> Local variables* from the "Element" list and disable or change the style.

Comment: Any idea how to export these settings somewhere, so I can use them in another workspace? they're tied to a single workspace.

Comment: @Buffalo I have not tried this, but maybe File -> Export -> General -> Preferences -> Java Appearance Preferences? Them import again with File -> Import -> ...

Comment: I've tried exporting "All", but there's no "Java Appearance Preferences".

Comment: Fixed it by copying the tweaked workspace settings (\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.runtime\.settings) to the other workspace.

Thanks!

Comment: @Buffalo I just tried it myself with "Export all" and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Found it. It wasn't under General -> Appearance, but rather **Java** -> **Editor** -> **Syntax coloring**: **Local variables**.

[image]